# Making Squared Words

Tags: code-golf, string

**The Challenge**

Your task is to create a program that takes any given string input, and outputs the input in a squared format. Empty strings should return an empty string.

**Examples**

Given the input:

```
golf
```

Your program should output:

```
golf
o  l
l  o
flog
```

Input:

```
123
```

Output:

```
123
2 2
321
```

Input:

```
a
```

Output:

```
a
```

Input:

```
Hello, world!
```

Output (notice the space between the , and w - the gap is not just a newline):

```
Hello, world!
e           d
l           l
l           r
o           o
,           w

w           ,
o           o
r           l
l           l
d           e
!dlrow ,olleH
```

**Scoring**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, my apologies I had forgotten to add that.

Comment: No worries, just double checking. Nice first challenge BTW! Welcome to the site :)

Comment: @SpookyGengar Would you add a test case for a one-letter input?

Comment: @musicman523 don't I already have one? The third example involving just the letter 'a'.

Comment: Is empty string allowed to output to STDERR? (aka can I error out for null input)

Comment: @SpookyGengar my bad, I'm blind apparently

Comment: Ooh, this gave me an idea I have forgotten a while ago.

Comment: Do you accept the input itself as a part of the output? As in - the program doesn't output the the top line? That's the design of this answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133927/71498 and I'm looking for confirmation before I retract my downvote.

Comment: Do you accept the output as a list of (meta-approved) strings that do not have newline characters? Some solutions (e.g. Haskell) are already doing things that way, but I wanted to check.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
θ‖Ｏ↙↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRKNQ05orKDUtJzW5xL8stSgnsUDDyiW/PM8nNa1ERwHMDMpMzyjRtP7/Pz0/J@2/btl/3eIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @CarlosAlejo. Explanation:

```
θ       Print the input string, making the top row
 ‖Ｏ     Reflect with overlap...
   ↙    ... down and left, to create the left side
    ↘   ... down and right, to create the bottom and right sides
```

(Multiple directions to the Reflect command run consecutively rather than simultaneously.)

Comment: Wow, jesus, I still think Charcoal was the coolest esolang idea.

Comment: You can save two bytes if you just print the input string and reflect it downleftwards and downrightwards: `θ‖Ｂ↙↘`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRKNQ05orKDUtJzW5xKm0pCS1KC2nUsPKJb88zyc1rUQHzArKTM8o0bT@/98jNScnPzy/KCflv27Zf93iHAA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Comment: Now that I think of it, maybe I should have used `ReflectOverlap` instead of `ReflectButterfly` to avoid flipping characters. :-)

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where a golfed answer in an esoteric language is easier to read and understand than the full ungolfed versions of popular general purpose languages.

Comment: Your answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173654/61613) also works for 4 bytes.

Comment: You really just crafted this programming language for this challenge, didn't you?

Comment: @arminb I didn't create this language, although I have contributed some bug fixes.

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> <s>16</s> 11 bytes

```
otYTO6Lt&(c
```

Try it at [**MATL online!**](https://matl.io/?code=otYTO6Lt%26%28c&inputs=%27Hello%2C+world%21%27&version=20.2.1)

*EDIT: The code works in release 20.2.1, which predates the challenge. The link uses that release. (In 20.2.2 the code would be shorter, but it postdates the challenge).*

#### Explanation

```
o     % Implicitly input a string. Convert chars to ASCII codes
t     % Duplicate
YT    % 2-input Toeplitz matrix
O     % Push 0
6L    % Push predefined literal [2, -1+1j]. When used as an index, this is
      % interpreted as 2:end-1 (indexing is 1-based)
t     % Duplicate
&(    % 4-input assignment indexing. This writes 0 at the square formed by
      % rows 2:end-1 and columns 2:end-1 
c     % Convert to char. Char 0 is shown as space. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Very impressive! :) Is it possible to remove the blank line at the bottom of every output, or is that needed for functionality?

Comment: @SpookyGengar It's a very common request to allow a single trailing newline.

Comment: @SpookyGengar Thanks! MATL always displays a trailing newline. As Jonathan says, that's usually allowed

Comment: @LuisMendo You learn something new everyday. :) Thanks for the submission - definitely the best so far!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>29 22</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*[Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) <s>will</s> [trounce+d](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133677/53748) this score...*

```
J⁶ẋa0,1¦"ṚṚ;$ṖŒḌY
```

A monadic link taking and returning a lists of characters; or a full program printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/rUeO2h7u6Ew10DA8tU3q4cxYQWas83Dnt6KSHO3oi////r1SekZ@TqgQA)**

#### How?

```
J⁶ẋa0,1¦"ṚṚ;$ṖŒḌY - Link: list of characters, w     e.g. "whole"
 ⁶                - literal space character              ' '
J                 - range(length(w))                     [1,2,3,4,5]
  ẋ               - repeat                               [" ","  ","   ","    ","     "]
         Ṛ        - reverse w                            "elohw"
        "         - zip with:
       ¦          -   sparse application of:
   a              -     and (vectorises)
    0,1           -     to indexes: [0,1] (last and 1st) ["e","ll","o o","h  h","w   w"]
            $     - last two links as a monad:
          Ṛ       -   reverse                            ["w   w","h  h","o o","ll","e"]
           ;      -   concatenate                        ["w   w","h  h","o o","ll","e","e","ll","o o","h  h","w   w"]
             Ṗ    - pop (remove last entry)              ["w   w","h  h","o o","ll","e","e","ll","o o","h  h"]
              ŒḌ  - reconstruct matrix from diagonals    ["whole","h   l","o   o","l   h","elohw"]
                Y - join with newlines                   "whole\nh   l\no   o\nl   h\nelohw"
                  - if running as a full program implicit print
```

Comment: Very cool! So far the shortest solution, but does not work with single-character inputs, and strings consisting of numbers i.e. '123'.

Comment: Ah I will have to handle the single character edge case, yes. It does work with digit-character strings, the program input really should be quoted, like `'Hello'`, "Spooky's", `"123"`, etc. (Python is used to interpret input).

Comment: @SpookyGengar - fixed it up for the 1-character case.

Comment: Nice length reduction!

Comment: You're right about Charcoal.

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks, three different approaches used rather than just plain glfng.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Same as my answer then, haha

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah a similar approach for sure!

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>84</s> 78 bytes

```hs
f s@(_:x)|_:y<-r x=s:[a:(y>>" ")++[b]|(a,b)<-zip x y]++[r s];f s=[s]
r=reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc1BCoMwEEDRfU8xiIsEaw@QGuk9QpBYRgxNU5mxJRHvnmb74fFXxy8MoZQF@CEmleQ5qTz0BEmzMk6JPI4NNLLrzGxP4a6zHPrDb5Ag2xoJ2N4r1obthTThD4mxvJ2PoMHHHck9d2jhG4OPyLelrHX4@QM)  Usage: `f "test"`. Returns a list of lines.

**Edit:** -6 bytes thanks to dianne!

Comment: you can save a few bytes by using the pattern guard as a guard and defining a synonym for `reverse`;  `r=reverse;f s@(_:x)|_:y<-r x=s:[a:(y>>" ")++[b]|(a,b)<-zip x y]++[r s];f s=[s]` is 78 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 109 bytes

```c
i,j;f(char*s){for(i=j=printf("%s\n",s)-2;1[++s];)printf("%c%*c\n",*s,i,s[j-=2]);for(;*s*~i--;)putchar(*s--);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxBDsIgEEDRqxCSJgxlFnY74SS1CxxFIRENU1dNvTqWjev/8xjvzK0llykafoRqBbb4qib57N81lTUaPci5aCeAE53mcZSF4J94sNyrFZeczBn9tAB1gazYb0I85s/aaWMFEWhvz5CKAbWpAwgXvt40kNrbDw)

Noteworthy tricks:

- Instead of wasting bytes on `strlen`, we simply grab the length of the string while simultaneously printing the first line:

  ```c
  i=j=printf("%s\n",s)-2
  ```

  This works because `printf` returns the number of bytes written.
- For the middle lines, we need to loop over the string but exclude both the first and last character. This is achieved with the condition

  ```c
  1[++s]
  ```

  (which is shorter than `(++s)[1]`), which skips the first character due to the `++`'s being in the condition and skips the last one by stopping when the character past the current character is `'\0'` (rather than stopping *at* `'\0'`).
- In the body of the first loop,

  ```c
  printf("%c%*c\n",*s,i,s[j-=2])
  ```

  we print the current character, then the appropriate "mirrored" character (keeping track with `j`, which does go into the negatives, resulting in the odd situation of indexing into a string with a negative number) padded to a length of `i` with spaces (where `i` is conveniently `strlen(s) - 1`).
- The reversed printing on the last line is pretty straightforward; the only trick is the `*s*~i--`, which is the shortest way to get `i+2` iterations of the loop body (which doesn't depend on `i`; all `i` is used for is to count). The funky `*s*` part makes sure the loop doesn't run if `*s` is `'\0'`, which happens on length-1 input.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 40 bytes

```matlab
@(s,t=toeplitz(s),u=t(x=2:end-1,x)=32)t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNYp8S2JD@1ICezpEqjWFOn1LZEo8LWyCo1L0XXUKdC09bYSLPE@n9iXrGGUnp@TpqS5n8A)

It is my answer but posted after @Luis [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133659/62451)

Comment: Very nice answer. Btw: your code crashed the GNU Octave development branch 4.3.1 (b481a9baeb61) and is now part of the test suite :-) http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/c94e9509461b

Comment: @Andy Thanks and welcome to codegolf! I glad if it can help improving Octave project!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>89</s> <s>81</s> <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```python
i=input();n=k=len(i)-2
print i
exec'print i[~k]+" "*n+i[k];k-=1;'*n
if~k:print i[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCoAgEADQ3a@QFktx0FHxS8IpjI6LS8OgFn/dlhofvPzU7SDbOwSgfNVx8hQw7IlGmLRl@QSqHFi60yI@zA2jGvggScGM0aMOxgtJDNaG7k/OaRN7F6WIFw)

Comment: Same failure for length 1 strings that mine had.

Comment: @StepHen fixed it and golfed further :D

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 113 bytes

```r
function(s){n=length(s<-strsplit(s,'')[[1]])
m=matrix(' ',n,n)
m[n,n:1]=m[,1]=m[1,]=m[n:1,n]=s
write(m,'',n,,'')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxCgIxEEX7PcVazQTGIq2Y3htYhBSiGw0kE8nMoiCePWZt3ofH57UeXY8rXzVVRjEfdnnhuz5QjnvRJs@cFIUAjPc2BDMVVy7a0hthBmLiYfyYgw2uePrT0sahiIOT6dWSLlhGY/y30rdHhNOSc6X5XFu@7cD0Hw)

Comment: My answer to the [dupe challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173761/67312) is shorter -- what a difference a year can make!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 19 bytes

```
ÂDÂø¦¨Dgú€Ás)˜»Igi¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P8wNWFiMWX//8OCRMOCw7jCpsKoRGfDuuKCrMOBcynLnMK7SWdpwqj//2Fi)

**Explanation**

Example with `input = golf`

```
ÂDÂ                  # bifurcate, duplicate, bifurcate
                     # STACK: 'golf', 'flog', 'flog', 'golf'
   ø                 # zip the top 2 items
                     # STACK: 'golf', 'flog', ['fg', 'lo', 'ol', 'gf']
    ¦¨               # remove the first and last element
                     # STACK: 'golf', 'flog', ['lo', 'ol']
      Dg             # get the length of the list
                     # STACK: 'golf', 'flog', ['lo', 'ol'], 2
        ú            # prepend that many spaces to each element
                     # STACK: 'golf', 'flog', ['  lo', '  ol']
         €Á          # rotate each right
                     # STACK: 'golf', 'flog', ['o  l', 'l  o']
           s         # swap the top 2 items
                     # STACK: 'golf', ['o  l', 'l  o'], 'flog'
            )˜       # wrap in a flattened list
                     # STACK: ['golf', 'o  l', 'l  o', 'flog']
              »      # join on newline
               Igi¨  # if input is length 1, remove last char
```

The fix for 1-letter input was quite expensive.
I feel like a different approach might be better now.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 88 bytes

```
w=input();p=print;l=len(w)-2
[p(w[n+1]+' '*l+w[l-n])for n in range(l)]
l+1and p(w[::-1])
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to the site as well! I believe that `l+1 and` could be rewritten as `l+1and` to save a byte.

Comment: @WheatWizard edited - thanks! I was surprised that worked...

Comment: It will work except for the case of `0or`, where python fails to parse because `0o` is an octal prefix.

Comment: When I run this, it doesn't seem to print the top line...
https://tio.run/##FcoxCsQgEAXQPqeYLk7EwqRL8CRiEVh3Iww/gxhkT@@yr376bdeNbYweCvRphg8NWgvaIUEyTGe3TlFNj7A@2ZnmRWyP4pD4fVcCFVA98clGOE1i/YkX/f@@O594jHblHw

Comment: @CotyJohnathanSaxman the solution re-uses inputted word as first line (i.e. try copy-pasting into .py file and run from terminal and you'll see). You could add "p(w);" before the "l=len(..." to obtain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>99</s> 88 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to musicman523.*

```python
lambda s:s[1:]and[s]+[s[i]+' '*(len(s)-2)+s[~i]for i in range(1,len(s)-1)]+[s[::-1]]or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcuxDsIgEIDhVzknwLYmdCRx9w060BswgJ7Bo@G6uPjqaIzz//3ba79Xnns@r72E5zUGECfeOgwcveDgxRMOCtRRl8RazDSbQfybMNcGBMTQAt@StuO/W/O7nJss4tdI3xrxDmpldXpUYp21uqRS6ghLbSUelDH9Aw)

Returns a list of strings.

Comment: Close! The output is not exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcuxDsIgEADQXzmnAwFjGUnc/QMHylDTEo8gEK6L/jza7S2vffZXLXbE2zzy8n6uC7DDueAlVSrCc1CeFAKeRd6KYGmsVAli7UA6ARX4UhPsJ2emoNkb664H5f@xdweDHK1T2SEKvG85Vw2P2vN6Qjl@) by moving `s` and `s[::-1]` into the `join`

Comment: This doesn't quite work for length-1 strings

Comment: Just to note, all the issues have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html), <s>215</s> 199 bytes

```swift3
let s=readLine()!,c=s.characters,r:[Character]=c.reversed(),b=c.count
print(s)
if b>1{for i in 0..<b-2{print("\(r.reversed()[i+1])\(String.init(repeating:" ",count:b-2))\(r[i+1])")};print(String(r))}
```

[Try it online](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5972645d4d6fc06b79b9e5d0)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 58 bytes

```
{(' ',⍵)[x+(x←∘.{((c-1)=⍺⌈⍵)∨0=⍺⌊⍵}⍨r)×o⌊⌽⊖o←∘.⌈⍨r←⍳c←≢⍵]}
```

With `⎕IO←0`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLjSgGS1hrqCus6j3q2a0RXaGhVAkUcdM/SqNTSSdQ01bR/17nrU0wGSfdSxwgDC7QJyax/1rijSPDw9H8ztfNQ1DULmQ/WDNa0oAvF6NyeDqM5FQG2xtf//pymoJ6pzAUlDI2Mw7ZGak5OvqA4A)

**How?**

`c←≢⍵` - length of the string

`r←⍳` - range

`o←∘.⌈⍨` - outer product with minimum

```
123
223
333
```

`o⌊⌽⊖` - minimalize with itself turned 180<sup>o</sup>

```
123  ⌊  333  =  123
223  ⌊  322  =  222
333  ⌊  321  =  321
```

`×` - multiply with

`x←∘....⍨r` - outer product of the range with

`((c-1)=⍺⌈⍵)∨0=⍺⌊⍵` - the frame of the matrix

```
111  ×  123  =  123
101  ×  222  =  202
111  ×  321  =  321
```

`x+` - add the frame

```
111  +  123  =  234
101  +  202  =  303
111  +  321  =  432
```

`(' ',⍵)[...]` - get by index from the string concatenated to space

Comment: Can `⍉⊖⍉⊖` be `⌽⊖`?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 128 bytes

```
(c=Column;g=Length[x=Characters@#]-1;If[g==0,#,c@{#,c@Table[""<>{x[[i]],""<>Table[" ",g-1],x[[-i]]},{i,2,g}],StringReverse@#}])&
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 96 bytes

```c
i,l;f(char*s){for(i=l=puts(s)-2;--i;)printf("%c%*c\n",s[l-i],l,s[i]);for(;l+1;)putchar(s[l--]);}
```

Bonus version (122 bytes):

```
x,y,i,l;f(char*s){for(i=l=puts(s)-1;++i<l*-~l;putchar(x==l?10:x%~-l*(y%~-l)?32:s[(x*y?l+l-2-x-y:x+y)%l]))x=i%-~l,y=i/-~l;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>108</s> 112 bytes

```js
let f = 

s=>(n=s.length)<2?s:(r=[...s].reverse()).slice(1,-1).reduce((a,v,i)=>a+`
`+s[i+1].padEnd(n-1)+v,s)+`
`+r.join``

o.innerHTML = f("hello folks!")
```

```html
<pre id="o"></pre>
```

**Less golphed**

```
s=>
   (n=s.length) < 2 ?    // record and check length
   s :                   // s has 0 or 1 char, else
   (r=[...s].reverse())  // reverse characters,
   .slice(1,-1)          // exclude 1st and last
   .reduce((a,v,i)=>     // append inner lines
      a +'\n' +s[i+1].padEnd(n-1) + v
    ,s)                  // to first line
    + '\n' +r.join("")   // append characters reversed
```

Thanks to Justin Mariner for saving lots of bytes, which then all got used up adding the zero or single character check needed to comply with the challenge. You get that :-(

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by making the second line `\`+s[i+1].padEnd(s.length-1)+v,s)+\`` and by using `r.join\`\``.

Comment: Thanks @JustinMariner for the tips about `String.prototype.padStart` and tagged template literals. I needed that to help keeping the addition of the length check to a minimum :-)

Comment: Your spacing is one character too short now; you can fix that and save a couple more by doing `(n=s.length-1)?(r=<...>+r.join\`\`:s` and using `padEnd(n)`. If the length is `1`, `length-1` is `0` (false).

Comment: @JustinMariner spacing is fixed, but I've kept the length test - as I understand it, both zero length strings and strings of one character return themselves without either carriage return or repetition of the string.

Comment: `padEnd` is ES2017.

Comment: @Neil thanks, a new standard to read!

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](http://php.net/), 118 bytes

```
echo $s=$argv[1];$l=strlen($r=strrev($s))-1;for($i=$l-1;$l&&$i;)echo "\n".str_pad($r[$i],$l).$s[$i].(--$i?"":"\n$r");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvRCoMgGIbhW3HyEQopdDoXnXYPLUYst4SflN/RLt/Zzp6D901bKuU2pC0J/9yiQO6x8PuYutmB@vxh8rsCn2J/KGStTedekRVCD6oGNQ2C0/9f3ndpa/tIy1q3CWFuQdoin7TKGIRBymvtwFK7UsroiWIrvpFpvfwA)

```
echo $s = $argv[1];
$l = strlen($r = strrev($s)) - 1;

for ($i = $l - 1; $l && $i;)
    echo "\n" . str_pad($r[$i], $l) . $s[$i] . (--$i ? "" : "\n$r");
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>16</s> 10 bytes

```
∞∞?L2460ø∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJ7iiJ4/TDI0NjDDuOKIpyIsIiIsIkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEiXQ==)

-6 bytes by porting 05AB1E thanks to emanresu

Comment: [osabie port = 10](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJ7iiJ4/TDI0NjDDuOKIpyIsIiIsIkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>14</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

*Knew* there had to be a shorter way!

```
¬hU ÆÔÃÕÆÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=rGhVIMbUw9XG1A&input=IkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEi)

```
¬hU ÆÔÃÕÆÔ     :Implicit input of string U
¬              :Split
 hU            :Replace first element with U
    Æ          :Modify last element
     Ô         :  U reversed
      Ã        :End modify
       Õ       :Transpose
        ÆÔ     :As above
               :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 122 bytes

```py
i=input();l=len(i)
if l!=1:
    print(i)
    for I in range(1,l-1): print(i[I]+" "*(l-2)+i[l-I-1])
    print(i[::-1])
else:print(i)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3qzJtM_MKSks0NK1zbHNS8zQyNbky0xRyFG0Nrbg4C4oy80pAQpxp-UUKngqZeQpFiXnpqRqGOjm6hppWClAF0Z6x2koKSloaObpGmtqZ0Tm6nrqGsZpwA6KtrMD81JziVCuYoRAXQB2yYGEihAEA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>28</sup> 23 bytes

```
|._1}]0}|.,.~<:@#{."1,.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYo9C8IwFAD3/IrXBnxtSV6TRWiwEBTEQRxcnIqDtn4QCLg2yV@PxcHhhjvunbvC6GFdmA6RlYQT9AYQBCgwC5Jgdz7uc6CrjoOKgQSljbF8plILyjU7bWn5cSXmVFVcDsHKNlDdqF41bbIiRVPbF1nOxtvTwwT48G7CnyH@42F0zgu4@I@7Y/4C)

- `,.` Columnize the input:

  ```
  g
  o
  l
  f
  ```
- `<:@#{."1` Take "input length - 1" elements from each row, with space fills.  I'll show the spaces filled with `.` for clarity:

  ```
  g..
  o..
  l..
  f..
  ```
- `|.,.~` Zip with the reverse:

  ```
  g..f
  o..l
  l..o
  f..g
  ```
- `]0}` Replace first row with input:

  ```
  golf
  o..l
  l..o
  f..g
  ```
- `|._1}` Replace last row with input reversed:

  ```
  golf
  o..l
  l..o
  flog
  ```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gIûûŽ9¦Λ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3fPw7sO7j@61PLTs3Oz//xOTklMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GdWibvZJnXkFpiZWCkr0Ol5J/aQmEo/M/3fPw7sO7j@61PLTs3Oz/IMVc5RmZOakKRamJKQqZeVwp@VwKCvr5BSX6EDOhFJo1NgoqYLV5qf/T83PSuAyNjLkSuTxSc3LydRTK84tyUhS5EpOSU7gA).

**Explanation:**

```python
g    # Push the length of the (implicit) input
I    # Push the input itself
 û   # Palindromize it
  û  # And palindromize that again
Ž9¦  # Push compressed integer 2460
Λ    # Use the Canvas builtin with those three options
     # (after which the result is output immediately implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section How to compress large integers?)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž9¦` is `2460`.

As for some additional information about the Canvas builtin `Λ`:
It takes 3 arguments to draw an ASCII shape:

1. Length of the lines we want to draw
2. Character/string to draw
3. The direction to draw in, where each digit represents a certain direction:

```python
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

`gIûûŽ9¦` creates the following Canvas arguments:

- Length: the length of the input (e.g. `4` for input `"abcd"`)
- Characters: the double palindromized input (e.g. `"abcdcbabcdcba"` for input `"abcd"`)
- Directions: `[2,4,6,0]`, which translates to \$[→,↓,←,↑]\$

Because we only have a single length, the directions are leading here.

Step 1: Draw 4 characters (`"abcd"`) in direction `2` (\$→\$):

```python
abcd
```

Step 2: Draw 4-1 characters (`"cba"`) in direction `4` (\$↓\$):

```python
abcd
   c
   b
   a
```

Step 3: Draw 4-1 characters (`"bcd"`) in direction `6` (\$←\$):

```python
abcd
   c
   b
dcba
```

Step 4: Draw 4-1 characters (`"cba"`) in direction `0` (\$↑\$):

```python
abcd
b  c
c  b
dcba
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for an in-depth explanation of the Canvas builtin.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](http://lua.org), 104 bytes

```
print(s);for a=2,#s-1 do print(s:sub(a,a)..(" "):rep(#s-2)..s:sub(#s-a+1,#s-a+1)) end;print(s:reverse())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvNCoQwDIRfJdu9JFgFPSrefY1Is7BQrCT@PH4tqKfhm28m7pxtdJPEmDycSWP4uLzqf9nQaPglBR47/7W6hZDgEb3tM7Jnahp04KhXWbFsulLcsgBXrb@DCGQJw3tWOURNkCjnCw)

Comment: but you only used `p` once...

Comment: True... gonna change that.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES2017), 87 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].reverse(l=s.length-1).map((c,i,z)=>i?l-i?s[i].padEnd(l)+c:z.join``:s).join`
`
```

ES6 version: 93 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].reverse(l=s.length-1).map((c,i,z)=>i?l-i?s[i]+' '.repeat(l-1)+c:z.join``:s).join`
`
```

*Less golfed*

```js
s => (
  l = s.length-1,
  [...s].reverse().map( // scan string backwards
     (c, i, z) => 
     i != 0 // check if top row
     ? l-i != 0 // check if bottom row
       ? s[i].padEnd(l) + c // any middle row
       : z.join`` // bottom row: string reversed
     :s // top row: original string
  ).join`\n`
)
```

```js
F=
s=>[...s].reverse(l=s.length-1).map((c,i,z)=>i?l-i?s[i].padEnd(l)+c:z.join``:s).join`
`

function update() {
  O.textContent = F(I.value)
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value='Hello, world!' oninput='update()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: `padEnd` is ES2017.

Comment: @Neil thank you I'll change my heading

Comment: You can save a byte on your ES6 version by using `l+~i`, this avoids having to subtract 1 twice instead you can subtract 2 once.

Comment: @Neil it should be `l-~-i`

Comment: I was thinking of ```s=>[...s].reverse(l=s.length).map((c,i,z)=>i?l+~i?s[i]+' '.repeat(l-2)+c:z.join``:s).join`\n` ``` but ```s=>[...s].reverse(l=s.length-2).map((c,i,z)=>i?i+~l?s[i]+' '.repeat(l)+c:z.join``:s).join`\n` ``` also works.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>179</s> 161 bytes

*-18 bytes thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38550/thelethalcoder)*

```cs
using System.Linq;
s=>{int l=s.Length-1,i=1;var d=s.Reverse().ToArray();while(i<l)s+="\n"+s[i]+new string(' ',l-1)+d[i++];if(l>1)s+="\n"+new string(d);return s;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVA9b8IwEJ2bX3FlwZaTSJlNkFClqgNdaKUOlMGKL3CSsVufCUKI354GaClvuM@np3fXcNGEiL03W@Qv0yC8HTjhNjtmMGDH5NcwJ/@tL33jDDPMLvWVcQYnk6iBLpCFV0NeyNvqn3TG8843E05xEM3hmqfQQt1zPT2ST@BqLufo12lTVDnVle5MBDsMF9hhZBSyfA@zGM1BSL3fkENBEydZ1aNPP1K8pJXyuP/VFmMY566opLJLUmqlqRVuWt3od0wrdcS0ix5Yn3T/cHb7FDwHh@VHpISiFX/9Ao0dXjKYkVLf7jtl13jqX9C5kMM@RGcffwA)

<s>I'm not sure about the rules, if this is needed to byte count or not:</s>

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

Someone please correct me about this.

Ungolfed:

```cs
s =>
{
    int l = s.Length - 1, i = 1;
    var d = s.Reverse().ToArray();
    while (i < l)
        s += "\n" + s[i] + new string(' ', l - 1) + d[i++];
    if (l > 1)
        s += "\n" + new string(d);
    return s;
};
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! You are using Linq so you should include the `using` into your byte count. As you are using Linq `ToCharArray()` can be just `ToArray()`, do you really need it before the `Reverse()` though? As you are using `String` you either need to fully qualify it or include the using, however, this can be easily fixed by changing it too `string`. The `if` might be shorter as a ternary like `s+=l>1?if code:"";`. You can remove the `i++` from the loop and post increment it at `d[i++]`.

Comment: Initialise `i` with `l` like `int l=s.Length-1,i=1;`. And I think that might be it!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder thank you! I added your suggestions to the code. A few notes: I totally forgot that string does in fact have IEnumerable; String instead of string was a Java residue that I still fight with, ternary was in fact exactly as long suprisingly; and after your changes I changed for(;expr;) to while(expr) since it looks nicer and is the same byte count. Thank you again.

Comment: No worries! Ternaries sometimes are but usually come out shorter so is always worth trying them.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 191 bytes

```
(s)->{PrintStream o=System.out;int l=s.lenght();o.println(s);for(int i=0;i<l;i++){o.printf("%"+"s%"+(l-1)+"s%n",s.charAt(i),s.charAt(l-1-i));for(int i=0;i<l;i++){o.print(s.charAt(l-1-i));}}};
```

Comment: `(s)` can be just `s`. The loops with single lines inside can have their curly braces removed. You could return instead of printing if that will save you any bytes. You use `int i` in both loops, I can't tell if they're in different scopes but worth pointing out. Initialising like variables together usually saves bytes. `for(int i=0;i<l;i++){o.print(s.charAt(l-1-i));}` -> `for(int i=0;i<l;){o.print(s.charAt(l-1-i++));}`. You don't need the trailing semi colon.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ;) (not very familiar with Golfing). Will Optimize it later!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 85 bytes

Using the input for the top row :)

```
a=input()
b=len(a)
for i in range(b-2):print(a[1+i]+" "*(b-2)+a[-2-i])
print(a[::-1])
```

Comment: Are you sure this gives a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 106 bytes

```
..+
$&¶$&
O$^`.(?=.*$)

\G.
$&$%'¶
r`.\G
¶$%`$&
+`(.+)¶¶((.*¶)*).(.*)
¶¶$1$4$2
T`p` `(?<=.¶.).*(?=.¶.)
G`.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCgJBDEX7nMIiuyYz8EGxdNlyShvLRWKhIojK4tlygFxsnOke7z/@evs939dagUw8hvNIJ74YZJ6QWImWgjbwsA2n1bAUatFgrcsmyBoeLoIUrknRQKkr3vGB93S2r21M5uOEcChS/@1ExVDr4/O6/wE) Explanation:

```
..+
$&¶$&
```

If there are at least two characters, duplicate the input.

```
O$^`.(?=.*$)
```

Reverse the duplicate.

```
\G.
$&$%'¶
r`.\G
¶$%`$&
```

Turn the strings into triangles. The top triangle starts with the input and removes the first character each time, while the bottom triangle starts with the first letter of the reversed input and adds a character each time.

```
+`(.+)¶¶((.*¶)*).(.*)
¶¶$1$4$2
```

Join the triangles together, overlapping so that the last character forms the `/` diagonal.

```
T`p` `(?<=.¶.).*(?=.¶.)
```

Change all the characters to spaces, if they are at least one character away from the end on every side.

```
G`.
```

Delete any left-over blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 106 bytes

A functional version...

```
w=input();p=print;l=len(w)-2
def f(k):p(w[k]+' '*l+w[-k-1]);l-k>0and f(k+1)
l<0 or f(1)or l<1or p(w[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 100 bytes

```python
lambda a:'\n'.join([a]+(len(a)>1)*([a[i]+(len(a)-2)*' '+a[~i]for i in range(1,len(a)-1)]+[a[::-1]]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYu7DsIwDAB/xUyO@0BKx0gw8w9pBqMmYBScKqqEWPj10AEx3ulufW/3olNLp7llfl4XBnY4Kx4fRdR4Dr3JUQ3T2VK3s5e/GSfqELBn/5GQSgUBUaist2js8GsshX6/nBttCERtraIbJIOXmHMZ4FVqXg5I7Qs)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>138</s> 91 bytes

```
(b=Outer[" "&,#,#];Do[l={{1,k},{k,1}};b=ReplacePart[b,Join[l,-l]->#[[k]]],{k,Length@#}];b)&
```

You can try it online with by pasting the following at [the Wolfram Cloud Sandbox](http://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) and clicking "evaluate cell" or hitting Shift+Enter or Numpad Enter:

```
(b=Outer[" "&,#,#];Do[l={{1,k},{k,1}};b=ReplacePart[b,Join[l,-l]->#[[k]]],{k,Length@#}];b)&@{"g","o","l","f","y"}//MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) - 153 bytes

```
l:>:?v;l$-[r:or].
-$/-$>$: ?vao~1-l1
  ^1vv?(2:<
 1^\:>$:&05&60. >$:&04&60.
o 1^\l3-=?v$:2(?^:l3-=?v$' '
 $^/$-3l:$<   /1-$-3l:$<
   \-1+&05&60.\+&04&60.
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoibDo+Oj92O2wkLVtyOm9yXS5cbi0kLy0kPiQ6ID92YW9+MS1sMVxuICBeMXZ2PygyOjxcbiAxXlxcOj4kOiYwNSY2MC4gPiQ6JjA0JjYwLlxubyAxXlxcbDMtPT92JDoyKD9eOmwzLT0/diQnICdcbiAkXi8kLTNsOiQ8ICAgLzEtJC0zbDokPFxuICAgXFwtMSsmMDUmNjAuXFwrJjA0JjYwLiIsImlucHV0IjoiMjUiLCJzdGFjayI6IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIsIm1vZGUiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Make sure the initial stack setting is set to "chars", occasinally it bugs out and switches itself to numbers.

### Summary

[image]

The blue bar at the top `l$-[r:or]` prints the n-th letter. The rest of the code is mostly branches leading to `&04&60.` that jump to the nth letter printer.