# Making octogonal words

Tags: code-golf, string

Last Thursday user [@SpookyGengar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72476/spookygengar) delighted us with his/her first challenge about [Making Squared Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133650/70347). What if we double the number of sides?

#### The challenge

Take a string as input in any reasonable format you need (`string`, `char` array...) and output an octogonal representation of the input (also in any reasonable format: `string`, list of `string`s, `char` matrix...) as in the next examples:

```
Input: golf
Output:

   golf
  o    l
 l      o
f        g
l        o
o        l
g        f
 o      l
  l    o
   flog


Input: HelloWorld
Output:

         HelloWorld
        e          l
       l            r
      l              o
     o                W
    W                  o
   o                    l
  r                      l
 l                        e
d                          H
l                          e
r                          l
o                          l
W                          o
o                          W
l                          o
l                          r
e                          l
H                          d
 e                        l
  l                      r
   l                    o
    o                  W
     W                o
      o              l
       r            l
        l          e
         dlroWolleH


Input: a
Output:

a


Input: ab
Output:

 ab
b  a
a  b
 ba


Input: code golf
Output:

        code golf
       o         l
      d           o
     e             g

   g                 e
  o                   d
 l                     o
f                       c
l                       o
o                       d
g                       e

e                       g
d                       o
o                       l
c                       f
 o                     l
  d                   o
   e                 g

     g             e
      o           d
       l         o
        flog edoc
```

#### Notes

- Input will consist only of printable ASCII characters.
- Leading and/or trailing whitespaces and newlines allowed as long as the octogonal shape is maintained.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the sortest program/function for each language win!

Comment: "What if we double the number of sides?" <-- then charcoal would still win

Comment: Suggested testcase: `code golf`

Comment: @LeakyNun is `<Space>` considered printable?

Comment: @V.Courtois [yes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5869/48934)

Comment: @LeakyNun added test case.

Answer (score 10):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes (10 bytes noncompeting)

```
Ｆ⁸«✂θ⁰±¹↷¹Ａ⮌θθ»θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0JToZqLM6AoM69EIzgnMzlVo1BHwUBHwS81PbEkVcNQU1PTGiifWZZfEpSZnlECFAHyHYuLM9PzNIJSy1KLioFaNHUUCoHitVwQg4Ds///T83PS/uuW/dctzgEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⁸«                 Repeat for each side of the octagon
   ✂θ⁰±    ¹        Print the input except the last character
        ↷¹          Rotate 45° clockwise
          Ａ⮌θθ      Reverse the input string
              »θ    Print the input again, to handle the length 1 case
```

Alternative length 1 fix, also 16 bytes: [Verbose version.](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEXXzSlmOYEUdCe48gBKqScIcZoOhMYmYzbi2cfo8j3e/2H1JWSfVK@vJPwsvAnu9myWXABPFt5mmP7ynjgQ7g4ODm4UvRAere3lMHHLMnNcpZvOl1o5bjhTo1L7xDr4PX5UQ34QxJwWo2PTsaYv)

```
ＰθＦ⁸«✂θ⁰±¹↷¹Ａ⮌θθ
```

A Charcoal bugfix means that the following 10-byte code now works: [Verbose version.](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0RToZqLM6AoM69Eo1DTmovTN78sVcPKJzWtBMSDSFi55JfnBWWmZ5ToKASllqUWFacCFSNUhxbA1AfllySWpGoAmbX//yfnp6QqpOfnpHH91y37r1ucAwA)

```
Ｆ⁴«θ←↘⮌θ↖⟲
```

Comment: `⟲` seems like it should just do this. Lol

Comment: Umm, I don't think `code golf` works does it?

Comment: Oh, and this is in fact 16 bytes (replace `θθθ` with `θθ»θ`).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oops, sorry about that, I didn't think to test my fix for the length 1 case... my test record on the question hasn't been very good has it?

Comment: @Neil But what about the issue with `code golf`? I think that has to do with how Charcoal takes input, which, unfortunately, disqualifies it completely from this challenge as that can't be circumvented.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I think it's because of the way TIO passes input to Charcoal; if you add a newline you get a different result.

Comment: @Neil TIO doesn't explicitly add trailing stuff to the input, I think Charcoal uses something like `.split()` for input where if there's only one line it splits on spaces while if it's over multiple lines it splits on newlines.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well since Charcoal can take input as a Python array [it can be circumvented](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0JToZqLM6AoM69EIzgnMzlVo1BHwUBHwS81PbEkVcNQU1PTGiifWZZfEpSZnlECFAHyHYuLM9PzNIJSy1KLioFaNHUUCoHitVwQg4Ds//@jlZLzU1IV0vNz0pRi/@uW/dctzgEA)

Comment: @Neil Invited you as a collaborator if you want to/don't mind fixing bugs (I can explain how it works in chat or something), also even if you don't accept would you mind opening issues? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Neil It isn't exactly the way TIO passes input, rather it's the way Charcoal parses input (python eval -> split by newline -> split by space, using the first one that works)

Comment: Also [verbose of the second one](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKcks6AoM69Eo1DTmisAzLJyyS/P80lNK9FRAAn65pelaliFFgRlpmeUoCrSUQhKLUstKk4F6gbKBOWXJJak@gNFchILoJSGkYmZjoJPal56SQZY1f//0UrJ@SmpCun5OWlKsf91y/7rppQBAA)

Comment: Finally fixed the bug (theoretical one) (sorry)

Comment: @ASCII-only Actually I'd since golfed the second one down so that it doesn't trigger the verbose bug, sorry about that. The original code was `θ←↘⮌θ↖↓θ⟲ＯＯ↙²⁴⁶Ｌθ` which can't be written in Verbose mode.

Comment: @ASCII-only Wow that means I can even have input with newlines!

Comment: @Neil Oh, yeah I fixed that, so *that's* what you were talking about haha

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 156 bytes

```js
f=
s=>[...Array((l=s.length-1)*3+1)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>s[i+j-l?l*5-i-j?i+l*2-j?j+l*2-i?i%(l*3)?j%(l*3)?-1:j?i-l:l+l-i:i?l+l-j:j-l:j:l-i:l*3-i:i]||` `))
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=this.value?f(this.value).map(function(a){return(a.join``)}).join`\n`:``><pre id=o>
```

Returns a character array.

Comment: It seems to work only with strings of length 4.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Sorry, didn't check carefully enough. Conveniently, fix saved 2 bytes!

Comment: Oh my that's a lot of ternary `?:`s!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer good thing it's not python or that would be really verbose :P

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 247 bytes

```
(T=Table;k=Length[s=Characters@#];If[k==1,#,Column[Flatten@{#,T[""<>{s[[i]],T["  ",k/2-2+i],s[[-i]]},{i,2,k}],T[""<>{s[[-i]],T["  ",k+k/2-2],s[[i]]},{i,2,k}],T[""<>{s[[i]],T["  ",3k/2-1-i],s[[-i]]},{i,2,k-1}],StringReverse@#},Alignment->Center]])&
```

Comment: You don't need `Alignment` and you'd save bytes by using delayedset (`:=`) to reduce the repetition of `s[[i]]` and `s[[-i]]`, You get down to 224 bytes with these ideas:
    (T=Table;q:=s[[i]];r:=s[[-i]];k=Length[s=Characters@#];If[k==1,#,Column[Flatten@{#,T[""<>{q,T["  ",k/2-2+i],r},{i,2,k}],T[""<>{r,T["  ",k+k/2-2],q},{i,2,k}],T[""<>{q,T["  ",3k/2-1-i],r},{i,2,k-1}],StringReverse@#},Center]])&
Also, I have [an alternate solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135786/41105) that's only 145 bytes at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>79</s> <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```
j++K+]+*dJtlzzm+++*;-Jd@zd*;+ytdlz@z_hdSJjL*;t*3tlztC_B_zt__MC.tK
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B%2BK%2B%5D%2B%2adJtlzzm%2B%2B%2B%2a%3B-Jd%40zd%2a%3B%2Bytdlz%40z_hdSJjL%2a%3Bt%2a3tlztC_B_zt__MC.tK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=golf%0AHelloWorld%0Aa%0Aab%0Acode+golf&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>84</s> 79 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.*

```
Ål
VoA{A?(UÅw +Uê)£Y¥V*2+AªY¥V-A?X:SÃ:Vç +U+Vç
Wf cU¬£V?(V*3 ç hUg~Y)+X:XÃcWz2
```

Leading newline is part of program. Takes a string as input and returns an array of strings.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=CsVsClZvQXtBPyhVxXcgK1XqKaNZpVYqMitBqlmlVi1BP1g6U8M6VucgK1UrVucKV2YgY1Wso1Y/KFYqMyDnIGhVZ35ZKStYOljDY1d6Mg==&inputs=ImdvbGYi,IkhlbGxvV29ybGQi,ImEi,ImFiIg==,ImNvZGUgZ29sZiI=&flags=LVI=) with the `-R` flag to join the resulting array with newlines.

Not my proudest work, but I got it down from ~100 bytes, at least. My idea here was to create the top and middle parts, then append the top portion, rotated 180°.

Comment: Nice. I don't see a lot of improvements right away, but you could change `Ul É` to `UÅl`, and switch V and W to save 2 more bytes: https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=CsVsClZvQXtBPyhVxXcgK1XqKaNZpVYqMitBqlmlQW5WID9YOlPDOlbnICtVK1bnCldmIGNVcSCjVj8oViozIOcgaFVnflkpK1g6WMNjV3oy&inputs=ImdvbGYi,IkhlbGxvV29ybGQi,ImEi,ImFiIg==,ImNvZGUgZ29sZiI=&flags=LVI=

Comment: Also, `AnV ?` -> `V-A?`, and `Uq £` -> `U¬£`

Comment: @ETHproductions Awesome, thanks! Can't believe I forgot about `¬`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>220</s> 213 bytes

- Surprisingly longer than I had imagined.

```python
a=input()
l=len(a)
r=range(l)
print'\n'.join(p.center(l*3-2)for p in[a]+(l>1)*([a[i]+(2*i-2+l)*' '+a[~i]for i in r[1:-1]]+[a[~i]+(l*3-4)*' '+a[i]for i in r]+[a[i]+(3*l-2*i-4)*' '+a[~i]for i in r[1:-1]]+[a[::-1]]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcy9CsMgFIbhPVfh5h8GYjIF0huxDpKa1HI4itihS2/dJkKhW7fzHR7e9Cr3iLpWtwRMz8J4Bwt4ZI53eckOd8@AdykHLPSKtH/EgCz1q8fiMwMxKs23mEkiAY2zksFl4IIZZ8IxtAhKS@CCEiqdeQd72nBYks0wq8Faadpfttb0lb@wkVOMAtRZnP715nZxXitd482TPcJGPw)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>168</s> <s>166</s> <s>147</s> 127 bytes

```
(n=Length@#;b=Array[" "&,3{n,n}-2];Do[l={{1,n+k-1},{k,n-k+1}};l=Join[l,Cross/@l];b=ReplacePart[b,Join[l,-l]->#[[k]]],{k,n}];b)&
```

This takes a list of one-character strings and outputs a matrix of one-character strings.

I saved 18 bytes by exploiting the symmetry to use `-l` and `Cross/@l` which takes [something like a cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra) of each of the two single 2D vectors to take `{x,y}` to `{-y,x}`. Basically, the two initial directions are East (top edge) and Southwest (top right edge). Then we add in 90-degree counterclockwise rotations of them with `Cross`: North for left edge and Southeast for bottom left edge. Then we add in the other four pieces using `-l` to flip the four we covered.

You can test it out on [the sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) with something like:

```
(n=Length@#;b=Array[" "&,3{n,n}-2];Do[l={{1,n+k-1},{k,n-k+1}};l=Join[l,Cross/@l];b=ReplacePart[b,Join[l,-l]->#[[k]]],{k,n}];b)&[{"H","e","l","l","o"," ","G","o","l","f"}]//MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7.1, <s>230 156</s> 155 bytes

```php
for($x=$e=strlen($s=$argn)-1;$n<9;$r[$y][$x+=$n+1&3?$n&4?-1:1:0]=$s[$i],$i+=($n+=!$i||$i==$e)&1?:-1)$r[$y+=$n-1&3?$n<6?:-1:0]=$r[$y]?:"";echo join("
",$r);
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b957bba1a94e5f7ba4b5799582a12cc626e1458).

**breakdown**

```
for($x=$e=strlen($s=$argn)-1;   # import to $s, set $e to length-1, init $x
    $n<9;                       # loop through 8 repetitions of string
    $r[$y][
        $x+=$n+1&3?$n&4?-1:1:0      # 3. increment/decrement $x depending on $n
    ]=$s[$i],                       # 4. copy character to current position
    $i+=(
        $n+=!$i||$i==$e             # 5. if first or last character of string, increment $n
    )&1?:-1                         # 6. if odd repetition next, else previous character
)
    $r[
        $y+=$n-1&3?$n<6?:-1:0       # 1. increment/decrement $y depending on $n
    ]=$r[$y]?:"";                   # 2. if empty, init row to string
echo join("\n",$r);             # output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
４Ｈ┐⁸ｋ⁸±＼＋⁸Ｌ１╋↶
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE0JXVGRjI4JXUyNTEwJXUyMDc4JXVGRjRCJXUyMDc4JUIxJXVGRjNDJXVGRjBCJXUyMDc4JXVGRjJDJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXUyMUI2,i=JTIyY29kZSUyMGdvbGYlMjI_,v=8)